# Search for 2 but not for 3 tab characters

Tags: search, tab-characters

I want to search in Vi for two tabs but not for three or more tabs. I tried several things like this:

```
/\t\t\(\t\)@!
```

But nothing works. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> :/\t\t(\t)@!

Your regular expression is almost valid, except that you need to use `\@` instead of `@`.

However first note, that using `:/` means the cursor will be put on the line matching the regular expression (this is usually used as an address, see [`:help :/`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3A%2F)), which is different from searching. For searching use the `/` command.

Second, using `\t\{2\}\t\@!` should work, but note, that this will match lines having more than two tabs, because the match would simply start at a later `\t`. So you need to anchor your match at the beginning to match non-tabs as well. Something like this might work:

```
/\%([^\t]\|^\)\zs\t\{2\}\t\@!
```

Which comes down to:

```
/         - start a search command
\%(...\)  - start a group
[^\t]     - match a non-tab
\|        - OR
^         - start of line
\zs       - start match now (not the previous char)
\t\{2\}   - at least 2 tabs
\t\@!     - not followed by another tab
```

Alternatively you can use `/\t\@<!\t\{2\}\t\@!` which is similar to the previous expression, except that it uses a zero-width negative look-behind assertion.

Note that those look-around assertions can be slow in Vim.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I found one issue: I got also matches with three tabs where the match starts at the second tab. I encountered this by adding a ^.